# Insufficient space for shared memory file when trying to run sample spark code on hdfs cluster

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, jvm, hdfs

i have a cluster of 2 vms both running linux and i have set spark and hadoop on them. Trying to run the spark sample code using :

```
spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.JavaSparkPi /home/user/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.4.jar
```

i get this error :

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Insufficient space for shared memory file:
   18383
Try using the -Djava.io.tmpdir= option to select an alternate temp location.
```

Running also `df -h` on my master node produces this result :

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           396M   43M  353M  11% /run
/dev/vda1        30G   28G     0 100% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           396M     0  396M   0% /run/user/1000
```

What can i do to solve this error?

After searching online i found this command : `sudo apt clean` which solved the problem temporarily but the error keeps popping up.

Any ideas?

Comment: `/dev/vda1  30G  28G  0 100% /` - your root partition is full. Free some disk space by cleaning up unused files or use larger disks.